# liminf and limsup of events: complement

Tags: probability, limsup-and-liminf

Consider a sequence $A_i, i \geq 1$ of Events.

At one point in our lecture, we have used:

$$P[\limsup_i A_i]= 1 -P[\liminf_i A_i^c]$$

with the reasoning that we can use de Morgan's rule.

At some other point however, we write

$$P[\liminf_i A_i] = 1- P[(\liminf_i A_i)^c] = 1- P[\liminf_i A_i^c] \geq 1- P[\limsup_i A_i^c]$$

arguing that $\liminf_i A_i^c \subseteq \limsup_i A_i^c$.

Which is true? Is $(\liminf A_i)^c = \limsup A_i^c$ or equal to $\liminf A_i^c$?

Thanks!

Comment: You have $\liminf A_i^c = (\limsup A_i)^c$ and $\liminf A_i^c \subseteq \limsup (A_i^c)$. Notice that the right hand sides of both equations are _not_ necessariliy the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$(\liminf A_i)^c = \limsup A_i^c$$

Pf:

$$LHS = (\liminf A_i)^c = (\bigcup_{m \ge 1} \bigcap_{n \ge m} A_i)^c$$

$$= \bigcap_{m \ge 1} \bigcup_{n \ge m} A_i^c = RHS \ QED$$

2. $$\liminf A_i \subseteq \limsup A_i$$

Pf:

$$\omega \in \liminf A_i$$

$$\to \exists m \ge 1 \ s.t. \omega \in A_m, A_{m+1}, ...$$

Now $\forall n \ge 1,$ we must find $A_i$ s.t. $\omega \in A_i$ and $i > n$

Case 1: $n < m$

Choose $i = m$

Case 2: $n \ge m$

Choose $i = n+1$

QED

Comment: Do I see this right that then the first equality I wrote in my question is wrong?

Comment: @user146358 your 1st eq is right

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then, why isn't, in the second equation:

$P[\liminf_i A_i]=1-P[(\liminf_i A_i)^c] = 1- P[\limsup A_i^c]$

why is there some detour needed using that $\liminf_i A_i^c \subseteq \limsup_i A_i^c$?

Comment: @user146358 What do you mean? In OP: Your 2nd eq is right. Your 3rd eq is wrong. Your. In comment: Both eq are right. None of the right equations seem to use that inclusion

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Then I have understood everything correctly from the beginning and what confused me was that the lecturer (accidentally) mentioned that we use this inclusion to conclude the second equality. 

thanks a lot!

Comment: @user146358 ayt. I can imagine such inclusions being used in INequalities however ...